# FloodFillPaintImage x start position and y start position

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am new at Imagick. I am trying to floodFillPaintImage from all the corner of image.

```
<?php
$im = new Imagick("test.jpg");
$im->scaleImage(0, 200);
$backgroundColor = $im->getImageBackgroundColor();
$im->floodfillPaintImage(new ImagickPixel('transparent'),300,$backgroundColor,0,0,false);
$im->floodfillPaintImage(new ImagickPixel('transparent'),300,$backgroundColor,200,0,false);
$im->trimImage(10);
$im->writeImage("test2.jpg");
$im->destroy();
```

In first case when x start position and y start position is 0 and 0 respectability, it works. But when I try x start position as 200 and y start position as 0. It throws an error.

My image is suppose to be of 200x200 and my code is suppose to run without any error. But, it doesn't run.

When I am giving x start position as 150 and y start position as 0. Then it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to flood-fill from outside the image boundary.

A 200x200 pixel image has coordinates ranging from (0, 0) to (199, 199).

More generally, a W * H pixel image has coordinates ranging from (0, 0) to (W-1, H-1).

---

After reading your comments, it seems that you are expecting the image to have been scaled to 200x200 pixels. Hopefully the following will help:

```
$im = new Imagick("test.jpg");

$im->scaleImage(0, 200);
list($w, $h) = array_values($im->getImageGeometry());

$backgroundColor  = $im->getImageBackgroundColor();
$transparentColor = new ImagickPixel('transparent');

$im->floodfillPaintImage($transparentColor, 300, $backgroundColor, 0,      0,      false);
$im->floodfillPaintImage($transparentColor, 300, $backgroundColor, $w - 1, 0,      false);
$im->floodfillPaintImage($transparentColor, 300, $backgroundColor, 0,      $h - 1, false);
$im->floodfillPaintImage($transparentColor, 300, $backgroundColor, $w - 1, $h - 1, false);

$im->trimImage(10);
$im->writeImage("test2.jpg");

$im->destroy();
```

Comment: It throws PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Unable to floodfill paint image'

Comment: What does `$im->getImageGeometry()` return? If the original image is taller than it is wide, then the image width will be less than 200.

Comment: array(2) {
  ["width"]=>
  int(500)
  ["height"]=>
  int(599)
}

Comment: So after scaling, the image will be about 167x200 pixels. The line `$im->scaleImage(0, 200);` scales the image to 200 pixels high, but keeps the aspect ratio the same.